# Draining the irrigation valves shown - confused about which side is inlet and identifying components?

Tags: plumbing, sprinkler-system, irrigation, winterizing

I'm trying to understand what I'm looking at with my sprinkler underground irrigation valve box, for the purpose of draining for a freeze. All of my relatives in Houston know how to do theirs, but mine (Austin area) looks completely different. Here's what it looks like:
[image: Pic of underground sprinkler irrigation valves]
From looking around here, I *think* C,D,and E are ports on a double checked backflow preventer? But I'm not sure which way the water actually runs. I found some stuff indicating it runs left to right, but then why would port A be on the inlet side?

Once I know water direction, what's the best way to drain for a short freeze spell? Turn off the inlet main valve (B or F) and then open C,D,E and possibly A? There's also a nub coming off the left side pipe at about a 45-degree angle, and I have no idea what that is.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Flow direction will be engraved on the side or bottom.   Stick your phone in selfie mode down there to see it.  Alternately clean off that red plate between D and E, you'll see the model number and can look up the manual on line.

Draining will only help if this is the low point of the whole irrigation system and the pipes generally run uphill with no low points.   Turn off the water supply, open ALL those valves and all the zone valves, and hope for the best.  There might be another drain valve near the supply cutoff.  Open that too.  This isn't reliable.

The preferred method is to use an air compressor to blow out the water.  If you or a friend have a large compressor.  If you can carry it it's too small.  At a high level you connect the compressor to the downstream port above (maybe A, but you need to confirm), one at a time open the sprinkler zones, and blow them for a couple minutes each.  These aren't complete instructions, if you are going to do that you should watch some youtube tutorials and read manuals.

You might find a landscaping company that will come do this for not too much money.

I'm surprised to hear that a freeze in Austin would be cold enough and last long enough to freeze the ground right through to the pipes and the water in them.  Didn't know that.   I'm in NJ, I have a landscaper come do this each November with a huge construction compressor.   He charges  much less than I would have to pay to rent the thing for 4 hours.

Comment: Thanks for all the advice. After digging (not literally) more, I realized the source of my confusion. The flow is indeed left to right. There is a separate isolation valve in a different spot next to that box. That guy gets turned off and then the test port locations make more sense.

Comment: Also, I may be being unnecessarily paranoid. I've never winterized one of these before in the 15+ years in the area, but the forecast keeps getting worse, with a low of 6 and a high of 21 currently set for Monday. Maybe that's not enough for pipes underground, and I'm sure y'all up North chuckle at that, but it's way deeper of a freeze than we generally get.

Comment: Just looked at your weather report, holy cow.   It can't hurt for you to do this.  While you're figuring things out, turn off the water supply, open every drain valve you can find and open all the zone valves using the manual override in the valve box.  This will partially drain the system.  A little.  Better than nothing if you can't do better.

Comment: Yeah, one digit temps are pretty unheard of here. Thanks for the recommendations.

Comment: @aggieNick02 I'm watching the news about all the frozen houses and power outs in Texas and wishing you the best.   I really hope your sprinklers are your biggest problem.  <3

Comment: Really ppreciate it. We lost power for 3 days but had what we needed (water, food, gas oven, fireplace). Ended up with snow through our ridge vents that wet ceilings in a couple rooms, but compared to what others are dealing with, that's nothing. I've never seen a storm like it. Pretty sure the irrigation survived unscathed, but that's low on my list now.anyways. :-)